# Python Fastest approach

Tags: python, math, time, numbers, time-complexity

I am looking for the **fastest**, minimum execution time approach to get all the numbers below a "n" number given by the user that are multi-perfect.
A number "X" is said to be multi-perfect if the sum of divisors is equal to "X" or "X" multiplied by a int between 2 to 11.

The algorithm that i have currently is this:

```
def function(n):
    list=[1]
    for X in range(2, n + 1):
        div = []
        for i in range(1, X):
            if X % i == 0:
                div.append(i)

        sum_div = sum(div)
        if sum_div == X:
            list.append(X)
        else:
            for k in range(2, 11):
                if (k * X == sum_div):
                    list.append(X)

    return list
```

As you can see this algorithm has 2 iterative structures that make it very very slow O(n^2), i am looking to improve that, any suggestion or advice?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "between"?

Comment: And why the artificial upper limit 11 at all?

Comment: Yeah but why do you change the definition from any multiples to only "up to 11"? Why do you define that a number whose sum of divisors is a larger multiple is not multiperfect?

Comment: Can you use that "smallest known k perfect number" to skip iteration on k? If we're dealing with factoring very large numbers, that subproblem is going to be fundamentally much harder than everything else here.

Comment: How large is your actual n? Different solutions might be fastest for differently large n.

Comment: I'm just voting for Kelly's answer and moving on. It's similar big-O but much much better for small numbers. If you want arbitrarily large N, you're not going to be able to find the factors.

Comment: The actual n is 10000 or greater.

Comment: Yes i can use that "smallest known k" to skip iterations.

Comment: How much greater?

Comment: Max around 100 000 000

Comment: It is not specific, so maybe less.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the sieve of Eratosthenes, but adding the divisors to their multiples:

```
def multiperfect(n):
    sums = [1] * (n+1)
    for i in range(2, n):
        sums[i::i] = [s + i for s in sums[i::i]]
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if not sums[x] % x]
```

Benchmarks with a few variations (`Kelly1` is my above solution, `original` is yours):

```
n = 1000:
  0.83 ± 0.00 ms  Kelly4
  0.89 ± 0.00 ms  Kelly1
  0.94 ± 0.00 ms  Kelly2
  0.95 ± 0.00 ms  Kelly3
 30.22 ± 0.33 ms  original

n = 10000:
 10.73 ± 0.05 ms  Kelly1
 11.21 ± 0.06 ms  Kelly4
 11.38 ± 0.11 ms  Kelly2
 11.74 ± 0.10 ms  Kelly3
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVVLbtswEF0W0Cm4KUwlamDaQVEI0Al6AQOqIDARmRKRKIGkAxuGT9JNNu2-V-gxepoOP5KoJEW7sDaS-ObzZt6Q_PZjOJqvvXx-_r43_MOn3-8YV32HjOiYMEh0Q69M-Escog01Qhtxr0e0Y1RmsN6wJ2_SD0xR06vRgDaNB4RhyvR9O7kqNjBqkqRhHPVKPAhJWyzTPEHwtJCmKEnlfjiE2yEhkaLygeFNhiS6RiSY2qcRT6hAZTUtWBcxu5AM7SJz-wgOMd-DUVGg9RIKEW_oMDDZYJEmE6z3Xe2TwReGrzSJAk5ogXbLkLaeMd5u9mGtZktDS_xxUSsh6Wt6kAw_oisooSjGtG-YvZHa2Shm9ko6yAvwmbXtkUzth4jaNpRUkAPLa5JOQoilEFFS61SKPBeVddUgkXAe2nrMYBUzKA_O5LCQyuazFcreeL9DBUodqojq5oJUOzpgGNMsWs3CdIL26SXobi9MV9zUNVCu65j0RZjeTkxhjxWIvCYt_4OwRbsZFYBmSLwYUMegq2wa8W_qfyHO9_LechtPkCyMcnhvwnsb3rfgAbG5je1cPaVBCWnwFcdkvV6D5M5ILsrbAuCN2WFg9ybKCS2bejJHLklezQUrpvetdeKjtX2o1swdhR4sQuwMJiObvj2aepEM08aCLkUas-erL_IkIcM5X4Vtbs9u25wTz-FwfMHv7ExsTHusa8wjeYyT24DahG2dn3GbGM5t1mAXtuRVWuZkXVVRjU4_vjrZawEb4PfxZsPP6NdPdHJ3hFu7dWswUatkalsdiT01-nVPlwNk2-mvJ9zS7q6huesuDMu-u2OqIOnSPNAeD0OTJkvZQnkuU4Ye2bFwnYnY-E6P_QIVYB9K2rG6hlhOGjtAozrzyrhkZyL1t224dMfL9w8)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from operator import add
from itertools import repeat

def original(n):
    list=[1]
    for X in range(2, n + 1):
        div = []
        for i in range(1, X):
            if X % i == 0:
                div.append(i)

        sum_div = sum(div)
        if sum_div == X:
            list.append(X)
        else:
            for k in range(2, 11):
                if (k * X == sum_div):
                    list.append(X)

    return list

def Kelly1(n):
    sums = [1] * (n+1)
    for i in range(2, n):
        sums[i::i] = [s + i for s in sums[i::i]]
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if not sums[x] % x]

def Kelly2(n):
    sums = [1] * (n+1)
    for i in range(2, n):
        sums[i::i] = map(add, sums[i::i], repeat(i))
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if not sums[x] % x]

def Kelly3(n):
    sums = [1] * (n+1)
    for i in range(2, n):
        sums[i::i] = map(i.__add__, sums[i::i])
    return [x for x in range(1, n+1) if not sums[x] % x]

def Kelly4(n):
    n += 1
    sums = [1] * n
    for i in range(2, n):
        for m in range(i, n, i):
            sums[m] += i
    return [x for x in range(1, n) if not sums[x] % x]

funcs = original, Kelly1, Kelly2, Kelly3, Kelly4

for f in funcs:
    print(*f(1000))

for n in range(2, 300):
    expect = original(n)
    for f in funcs[1:]:
        result = f(n)
        assert result == expect, (n, expect, result)

def test(n, funcs):
    print(f'\n{n = }:')

    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(100):
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: f(n), number=1)
            times[f].append(t)

    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

test(1000, funcs)
test(10000, funcs[1:])
```